# Integrating Spring 2.5 and a legacy Servlet Application

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring. I worked through the sections of this [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step)  that cover web flow.   My ultimate goal is to use Spring to implement new features in a legacy servlet webapp and then gradually replace the existing code making the servlet webapp into a Spring webabb.

So, to that end,  I decided to go through the web flow part of the tutorial again, changing names to make my own first "hello world" screen with Spring within the development copy of the legacy servlet application.

My problem is that when I put the servlet mappings for Spring into my web.xml, I get 404s trying to get to my landing page.

- I'm using WebLogic 9.2
- I converted the directory tree of my webapp to mimic the layout that Spring webapps use
- I copied spring.jar and spring-mvc.jar into my WEB-INF/lib

I made a simplified version of my web.xml, with just one legacy servlet in it ( for the landing page ) and Spring.  It works with the Spring stuff commented out, but not otherwise.   **Here it is, my WEB-INF/web.xml for the "abc" webapp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LogIn</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            com.utilities.LogIn
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogIn</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



  <!-- Welcome File List  -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

**This is my WEB-INF/abc-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

  <!-- the application context definition for the NSD webapp DispatcherServlet -->

  <beans name = "/hello.htm" class = "com.somecompany.web.HelloController"/>

</beans>
```

**Here is the code for my elementary controller:**

```
package com.somecompany.web;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("Returning view for CBS Search ....");

        return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp");
    }

}// end class
```

Again, my problem isn't with the controller or the view (jsp)...yet.   Right now, when I include the Spring servlet mappings in my web.xml,  I can't get to my landing page, I get a 404.  When I yank the Spring servlet mappings, that problem goes away.

I'm a raw beginner with Spring, so I am not sure where to look.

Comment: Hi Guys.  I corrected my typos.  Still no joy.  I'm starting a bounty. The winner gets 50 of my reputation points.

Comment: Any reasons for using Spring 2.5 and not 3.0? The annotation based configuration in 3.0 is really good and easier than configuring the bean in 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably with the `<url-pattern>` in your `web.xml`.  You cannot use "`.jsp`" as your mapped extension.

There is some pretty detailed discussion about the low-level reasons in [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?44676-java-lang-StackOverflowError-if-jsp-file-is-not-in-WEB-INF-folder)... but the long and short of it is that the "`*.jsp`" file extension is special to the underlying Java servlet specification.  You're trying to make Spring hijack that.  This is why the tutorial you linked to is using "*`.htm`" instead.

Trying changing your `<url-pattern>` in `web.xml` to something else (such as `*.htm`), and see if you can pull up your test URL with that extension.

Comment: I tried that.  I still have the same problem.  I get a 404 even trying to get to my landing page/welcome file

Comment: Did you change the bean name to match in "WEB-INF/abcspring-servlet.xml", and in the return value of your Controller?

Comment: I just went over that.  I noticed that in my samples above I had a commented out XML line that could confuse people.  I removed the comment.  

FYI, I obscured the names from what I have at work, just to be safe.

Comment: That's what I'm saying... the samples above reference "/abcspringsearch.jsp", which won't work.

Comment: I updated samples again.  Do you mean the slash in the bean name "/abcspringsearch.jsp" might be causing the problem?

Comment: No, I just mean that you can't use ".jsp" as the file extension in the places you are using it.  "/abcspringsearch.jsp" needs to be "/abcspringsearch.htm" (or something else) in "abcspring-servlet.xml"... and "abcspringsearch.jsp" needs to be "abcspringsearch.htm" (or something else matching) in the controller.

Comment: Okay.  I feel back to doing everything like in the tutorial ( see changed names in my examples ).  I'm still having the same problem.  My guess is I have a spelling error or something similar I haven't seen.  I'm going to walk through the tutorial again, very, VERY slowly.   Once I get it figured out I will post my answer for the sake of sanity and give you credit for what you wrote as it is an extremely useful tidbit that will no doubt prevent future hair pulling.

Answer (score 1):

What is your landing page? `/hello.htm`? your have just mapped everything with `htm` extension to a dispatcher, but you only have a controller which deals with `hello.htm`. You should get `404` if you are trying to access `/index.htm`. Change your mapping or create a controller for other urls.

However, if I were you, I would use Spring annotations in Spring 3.0 to configure the web application. It is much simpler.

Comment: I agree.  I found a bare bones Spring 3.0 MVC tutorial I was able to get working.  I am going to repost this question as Integrating a legacy Servlet App With Spring 3.1.   Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others its better to use Spring 3.0 which is more easier to configure. Since you have started with this i am giving some of my thoughts. You need to use something like SimpleUrlHandlerMapping which takes care of resolving your url pattern to appropriate controllers. Take a look at this spring reference documentation

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree.  I found a bare bones Spring 3.0 MVC tutorial I was able to get working.  I am going to repost this question as Integrating a legacy Servlet App With Spring 3.1.   Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Try a forward slash on your ModelAndView view name:

```
return new ModelAndView("/hello.jsp");
```